# Scroll-To-Top Function on button click (Android)

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a horizontal menu bar on the bottom of my app , in my main `Activity` (such as instagram does), which every time activates a different `Fragment`.

By clicking on the first button of my menu bar, it activates a `Fragment` which includes a `Tablayout`, the `Tablayout` contains 2 tabs. Each tab contains a `ListView`.

So what I want to do is, every time the first button of my menu bar is re-selected, scroll the `ListView` to the top.   Is there any way I can make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

try    `view.smoothScrollToPosition(0);`

you might need to wrap it in a post, as it's a bit flakey

```
 new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        }
    });
```